# Looping through multi-pal nodes with text fields in XSLT

Tags: loops, xslt

I need to loop through multipal nodes that have text field, to output into a tabel.

this is the XML:

```
<upload-notification>
<delay-message-list>
    <delay-message>Could not get Health Number from Card Number = null</delay-message>
    <delay-message>In order to qualify for the Vitalitydrive Integrator, </delay-message>
</delay-message-list>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
    <table width="800" align="left" class="normalFont" style="table-layout:fixed" border="1">
                        <col width="10%">
                            <col width="90%">
                                <tr bgcolor="lightgrey">
                                    <td align="left" bgcolor="lightgrey" width="800">
                                        please note:
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <xsl:for-each select="/upload-notification/delay-message-list">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        1
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="//delay-message"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </col>
                        </col>
                    </table>
                    <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

So far it only it only displays the one field in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this instruction

```
<xsl:for-each select="/upload-notification/delay-message-list">
```

you're trying to `for-each` over all the `delay-message-list` elements (there is only one).  Instead you need to `select` the individual `delay-message` elements, and then within the `for-each` take the `value-of` the node you're currently looking at, rather than your current code which always takes the value of the *first* `delay-message` element in the whole document.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/upload-notification/delay-message-list/delay-message">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

And if you want the rows to be numbered 1, 2, 3 etc. instead of all being numbered 1 then you can do that by replacing

```
        <td>1</td>
```

with

```
        <td><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></td>
```